# T-SQL change Time Portion of a DateTime, using another DateTime Time portion

Tags: t-sql, datetime, dateadd

I have a select statement that returns the following:

```
SELECT
   StartDate
   ,EndDate
FROM
   MyTable
```

And the result returns the following data:

[image]

What I want is change the **time portion** of StartDate using the value from EndDate. So that only the time portion of both dates is the same, taken from EndDate. I have to keep identical, down to milliseconds.

Is it possible using DATEADD function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`DateAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and [`DateDiff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, EndDate, startDate), EndDate) As StartDate,
       EndDate
FROM MyTable
```

I'm adding the days difference between the start date and the end date. 
Since the DateDiff have the later date before the earlier date, it returns the days difference as a negative number.

Another option that I'm guessing some people will find more readable is this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -DATEDIFF(DAY, startDate, EndDate), EndDate) As StartDate,
       EndDate
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: whoa, it works up to milliseconds, I didn't think about combining DATEADD with DATEDIFF. 
Thanks

Comment: yeah, all you change is the number of days, the time portion is not effected in any way by this.